# How to disable the update qty button in mini cart by default

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I want to disable the update qty button in mini cart by default, and when if the customer changed the qty then it should be enabled. Magento 2.4.2.

Comment: It is not clear, could you try to describe it again?

Comment: when i open my mini cart there is qty text box and update button if product has by default 1 qty its should disabled but if some one try change it update button should enable.

Comment: yes it hide button but dont want it to hide i want only disabled

Comment: do you mean if the item has default qty then display the Update button and disable it?

Comment: yes and enaabl if we change got it and disable again if default

Comment: not working html file is not getting override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js` is responsible for JS event: update item button when the item's qty changed.
- And `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` is responsible for the mini cart items template.

To achieve your goal, assume your VendorName is `IMT`, you module is `Checkout`, take the following steps:

Step 1: Create registration.php:

File path: `app/code/IMT/Checkout/registration.php`

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'IMT_Checkout', __DIR__);
```

Step 2: Create module.xml:

File path: app/code/IMT/Checkout/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="IMT_Checkout">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 3: Create the `requirejs-config.js` in your custom module.

File path: `app/code/IMT/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html':
            'IMT_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
    },
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar': {
                'IMT_Checkout/js/sidebar-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Step 4: Create the sidebar minxin file:

File path: app/code/IMT/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar-mixin.js

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var sidebarWidgetMixin = {
        /**
         * Customize to enable item buttons
         */
        _showItemButton: function (elem) {
            this._super(elem);

            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item'),
                itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');
            if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).prop('disabled', false);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Customize to disable instead of hiding the item button
         */
        _hideItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
            $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    };

    return function (targetWidget) {
        $.widget('mage.sidebar', targetWidget, sidebarWidgetMixin);

        return $.mage.sidebar;
    };
});
```

Step 5: Create the override html file: copy the content of `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` to your override file and replace `style="display: none"` by `disabled` to mark all item buttons disabled instead of hidden by default.

Below is the content of the override file based on Magento 2.4.5-p1, it is also able to apply to Magento 2.4.3 through 2.4.5:

File path: app/code/IMT/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <span data-bind="html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value.join('<br>'))"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && ['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value)"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && !['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                            <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty"/>
                <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            disabled>
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message notice" if="$data.message">
        <div data-bind="text: $data.message"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Step 6: Run the `setup:upgrade` command to make your new module active, and then compile code, deploy static content:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

You're done.